# Configuring static resource caching with IIS cache based on domain

Tags: caching

We came across a problem with regards to the IIS cache that is not taking the domain into consideration.
We have the following scenario:

1. Request page X from domain A.be
2. Page X requests a static resource om domain B
3. First request serves the static resource with access-control-allow-origin set to domain A.be (which is fine)
4. Now we request page X from domain A.fr
5. Page X requests the static resource from domain B again
6. IIS returns the cached version again with access-control-allow-origin set to domain A.be

This implies that the resource is unable to load as the header should have been set on A.fr instead...

Is there any way to configure the caching settings to not only look at the asset path but also take the domain into consideration?

Comment: Exactly which method are you using to set up the CORS headers?

Comment: through a Sitecore pipeline, setting it like: args.Context.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", $"{args.Context.Request.Url.Scheme}://{siteInfo.TargetHostName}");